# Local Security Policy - linux mint 15

Tags: linux, windows, security, linux-mint

http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=157&p=761606#p761606

I posted this in the forums a bit ago, and still haven't gotten any bites.
I've done a few searches on the webs and still haven't found any solutions

Problem: School network computer is preventing my laptop with Linux Mint15 and Windowzer8 to connect to the network.  It lets my Windows on but when i am on my Linux partition, I violate school networking policies.

Violation: Weak Password, weak password history, weak password resets. ( along those lines)

Schools "Solution": Update the "Local Security Policy" in the adminstration tools.

My question to you: What is the linux equivalent to "Local Security Policy".. If there isn't how do i go about beefing up the password requirements for the linux machine.
If I cannot do that, how do I work around this?

Comment: not programming related.

Comment: if you wanna put that in an answer form, ill mark it.. and @Kevin in the FAQ's first post ( things to ask about ) a specific programming problem
a software algorithm
software tools commonly used by programmers
practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession are things to be asking.. not specifically "programming languages" ... the network preventing me is hindering my programming ability at school.. thanks for the downvote tho

Comment: specific programming problem - no.  software algorithm - no. tools used by programmers - no. answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession - no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. The Windows security policy is managed through Active Directory from the domain controller, and your Linux system does not participate at that level. The best you can do is ask your school IT administrator if there is an approved way to connect your Linux system to the network. If there is not, and you persist in attempting to do so, or "find a workaround", you risk disciplinary action. These things are not taken lightly in today's security climate.